# Can the watch window value of a List<> be customised?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Overriding a class's ToString() is usually all you need to do to get custom formatting in the watch window, but when the class is derived from a list it doesn't seem to work.

```
class ListOfInts : List<int>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", this);
    }

    public static ListOfInts test = new ListOfInts() { 3, 4, 5 };
}
```

Inspecting 'test' in the watch window I get

```
ListOfInts.test             Count = 3   ListOfInts
```

and have to manually force the issue like so:

```
ListOfInts.test.ToString()  "3,4,5"     string
```

This is fine for a single list, but I have a large array of the things.  Is there a way to stop the default "Count = 3" format from taking priority?

Comment: Never used but try the [`DebuggerDisplay`-Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]
public class ListOfInts : List<int>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", this);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting to know why his quick watch window didn't use the overridden `ToString`. I guess it has something to do with his debugger settings (f.e. "show raw structure on objects in variables windows").

Comment: @TimSchmelter, In my LinqPad it does use the overridden `ToString()` without the `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute. Didn't check VS though.

Comment: Could be, although that particular setting doesn't appear to make a difference.  Using this attribute definitely does though -)

Comment: Note that it'll probably be a good idea to limit this to some degree, as in the case where it's a List<T> where T is a class whose ToString() implementation is slow-executing, this might cause unwanted delays (or otherwise just stop working after it times out for the first time). Something like `return string.Join(",", this.Take(20)) + this.Count > 20 ? "..." : "";` should fix