# Visual Studio 2015 looking at arrays in the watch window

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, watch-window

Say, I have an array of large objects I'm looking at.  The object class being:

```
Class Box
  Public length As Double
  Public breadth As Double
  Public height As Double
  ...
  ...
  Public blah as blah
End Class
```

Normally I use the watch window and expand the objects out and check out the object property I am interested in...

So after running my code in the watch I'd have something like:

```
- box[0]
    length      12      double
    breadth     10      double
    height      5       double
    ...
    ...
    blah        x       blah
+ box[1]
+ box[2]
.
.
.
+ box[x]
```

however, I was curious if there was a way to only see those properties of each object instead of all the other properties I'm not interested in along with it. For example, if i only wanted to see the height of each object like:

```
- box[0]
    height      5       double
- box[1]
    height      3       double
- box[2]
   height      2       double
.
.
.
- box[x]        x       double
```

Is this possible with the watch window?  or like the immediate window or..?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it counts a duplicate, per se, but one option might as answered in [Can the watch window value of a List<> be customised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040552/can-the-watch-window-value-of-a-list-be-customised)

Alternatively, you can customize how the Watch window displays different objects.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2017

(edit: previous version pointed to the NatVis, which is just for Native objects)